# Show that $f$ is a constant function

Tags: complex-analysis

Given that $f: \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a bounded holomorphic function. Prove that $f$ is constant.

There is a probably more generalized version of the problem here [Bounded holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C} \smallsetminus K$ are constant.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/643778/bounded-holomorphic-functions-on-mathbbc-smallsetminus-k-are-constant), but I want something simpler for this particular question. It mentions "If $K$
is finite, all its points are isolated, and since $f$
is bounded, removable singularities. Removing the singularities, we obtain a bounded entire function, which is constant by Liouville's theorem." I would like to make it more rigorous.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Riemann’s removable singularity theorem + Liouville. Or if you know Morera’s theorem, then you can use that as well to first deduce $f$ is entire, and then use Liouvile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f: \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is bounded holomorphic map.

$f$ is bounded in punctured disk around $0$, hence $0$ is removable singularity of $f$(by Riemann's theorem on removable singularity).
Hence $f$ has a unique holomorphic extension to $\mathbb{C}$ say $F$.

$F$ is a bounded entire function, hence constant (by Liouville's theorem) and $F\mid_{\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}}=f=c$
For some $c\in\Bbb{C}$

Answer (score 1):

[This theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann%27s_theorem) justifies why $0$ is a removable singularity, i.e. there exists a holomorphic $g : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ that coincides with $f$ on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$. Then apply Liouville's theorem.